# Select twice in another select statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following table schema and data

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    First_Name char(50),
    Last_Name char(50),
    Address char(50),
    Age  int,
    City char(50),
    Birth_Country char(25),
    Live_Country char(25),
    Birth_Date datetime
);

insert into Customer (first_name, last_name, address, age, city, Birth_Country, Live_Country, birth_date) values('John', 'Doe', 'Xi-Fu Road', 29,  'Tokyo', 'Japan', 'Japan','1988-11-19') ;
insert into Customer (first_name, last_name, address, age, city, Birth_Country, Live_Country, birth_date) values('Mary', 'Fai', 'Xi-Fu Road', 30,'Tokyo', 'Japan', 'Japan','1987-04-14') ;
insert into Customer (first_name, last_name, address, age, city, Birth_Country, Live_Country, birth_date) values('Tim', 'Potter', 'Gan-xuiu Road', 30, 'NewYork', 'US','Germany', '1987-04-11') ;
insert into Customer (first_name, last_name, address, age, city, Birth_Country, Live_Country, birth_date) values('Lala', 'Hua','Gong-Fu Road',  31, 'Bei-Jing', 'PRC', 'US','1986-12-11') ;
insert into Customer (first_name, last_name, address, age, city, Birth_Country, Live_Country, birth_date) values('Marcia', 'Changhua', 'To-Fu Road', 41 ,'London', 'French', 'Japan','1976-01-04') ;

CREATE TABLE Country_Info
(
    ID int,
    Country char(50)        
);


insert into Country_Info(ID, Country) values(0, 'Japan') ;
insert into Country_Info(ID, Country) values(1, 'US') ;
insert into Country_Info(ID, Country) values(2, 'Germany') ;
insert into Country_Info(ID, Country) values(3, 'PRC') ;
insert into Country_Info(ID, Country) values(4, 'French') ;
```

I want to know both the ID of the live_country and birth_country of a customer.

I use the following query

```
select ID from Country_Info, (select Birth_Country as birth, Live_Country as live from Customer) as tmp_table where 
birth = Country_Info.Country ;
```

The query only get the ID of the birth_country of a customer ;

But I want to get the ID of both the birth_country and the live_country, and show in two columns.

Is it possible to query once at a time?

Comment: What's your input value? I mean do you want to get data for a particular customer?

Comment: I want to get both the birth_country ID and live_country ID of all customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your data right now, try this

```
SELECT  C.first_name,C.last_name,
        Birth.ID as Birth_Country_ID,
        Live.ID as Live_Country_ID
FROM Customer as C
INNER JOIN Country_Info as Birth ON C.Birth_Country = Birth.Country
INNER JOIN Country_Info as Live ON C.Live_Country = Live.Country
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4678e/2
Then you add a `WHERE C.first_name = 'somename'` to look for specific customer.

But I suggest you add an auto_increment id to your Customer Table.
And instead of saving the country names in customer table, save the id of the country.

Comment: Thanks, bro. This is the answer that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Your database structure is not normalized.
You need to store the ID of birth_country and live_country in the table customer. Then use join to get the name of these country if neccesary

Answer (score 0):

you can use joins for this query, in join condition you should proper field_names in "on clause" to avoid replication, correct and fast result.

```
 select cu.first_name, ci.id as country_id, cu.Birth_Country, cu.Live_Country
 from
 Country_Info ci
 inner join Customer cu
 on ci.Country = cu.Birth_Country
```

in above query, I have clause "on ci.Country = cu.Birth_Country", which will show the country_id of birth_Country. if you want the id of live_country, just change the clause "on ci.Country = cu.Live_Country"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Country_Info` table to insert both **Birth_Country, Live_Country** in the form of create customer.

Save the **Birth_Country,Live_Country** as id instead of name.
Your Birth_Country,Live_Country is looks like below.You can get the values from Country_Info table.

```
<select name="Live_Country" id="Live_Country">
    <option value="1">Japan</option>
    <option value="2">Germen</option>
</select>
```

I guess your table structre is wrong,make the Country_Info table id as **auto increment** and **primary key**.
If you follow this structure you do not need to use any **join** in your query to retrieve the country name,you can get the country name by id.